# Programmatically get the yahoo messenger status

Tags: scripting, yahoo-api, yahoo-messenger

I'm interested to know how can I get the yahoo messenger status, as some sites do. I've find how to get the online/offline status, but not the invisible status as in this website: detectinvisible[dot]com

Do you have any idea?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

[This might help you](http://www.akxl.net/labs/articles/asp.net-c-sharp-instant-messenger-status-determination/)

Comment: ty, looks cool. I'll see if I can use the idea from PHP.

Comment: unfortunately it only works for online/offline status.